# No power or lights in bathroom

Tags: bathroom

The power is out in both of my bath rooms I checked.The breaker box nothing was  flipped. The lights won't turn on in either bath room an the outlet's don't have power. But I have power in the rest of the house I don't have power to GFCI in the kitchen I opened it up an checked it with the voltage reader I have  there no power to either of the GFCI top set of wires the one in the bath room or the kitchen but I do have power to the bottom set of wires

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You seem to have created two accounts; you should probably choose one and abandon the other.

Answer (score 8):

1 - "nothing was flipped" is not always clear. Sometimes a breaker can trip without being obvious. If you know which breakers power the bathroom circuits, flip those all the way off/on and see if that fixes the problem.

2 - Check the bathroom outlets. If any of them have a GFCI then press the Reset button. The outlets for the bathrooms may be sharing a circuit, all protected by one GFCI, and while lighting generally is on a separate circuit, it may be connected too.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea on GFCI, but don't just check the bathrooms. Check outside and by the kitchen sink. They are commonly used there too.

If its not a GFCI outlet being tripped, it could be what I ran into once. One of the push in wire connectors on the back of an outlet was not making a good contact. (I always use the screws) Pull the outlets and check for power with a meter, or even better, a non contact voltage tester. You can get one at Home Depot.  If an outlet has power into it, but not out, its either tripped, a bad outlet or a bad connection.

Comment: In my house, the GFI that protects the bathrooms is located in the garage so also check there.